# problem using an instance in a with_statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I've recently started to learn python , and I reached the **with** statement . I've tried to use it with a class instance , but I think I'm doing something wrong . Here is the code :

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import pdb

class Geo:

  def __init__(self,text):
    self.text = text

  def __enter__(self):
    print "entering"

  def __exit__(self,exception_type,exception_value,exception_traceback):
    print "exiting"

  def ok(self):
    print self.text

  def __get(self):
    return self.text


with Geo("line") as g :
  g.ok()
```

The thing is that when the interpreter reaches the **ok** method inside the with statement , the following exception is raised :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dec.py", line 23, in 
    g.ok()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ok'
```

Why does the g object have the type NoneType ? How can I use an instance with the **with** statement ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `__enter__` method needs to return the object that should be used for the "`as g`" part of the with statement.  See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), where it states:

- If a target was included in the with statement, the return value from `__enter__()` is assigned to it.

Currently, it has no return statement, so g gets bound to `None` (the default return value)